# Média de linhas repetidas

Tags: r, data, data.frame

Gente,

Eu tenho um data.frame da seguinte forma

```
Gene              12h        10d         6w

Slc39a10         1.52      -6.72     -1.84
Slc39a10         1.52      -6.72     -1.84
Mfsd6           -0.15      0.672      0.26
Mfsd6           -2.55     -54.53     -23.75
Hecw2            2.13      2.71       1.92
Hecw2           -7.30     -4.34      -6.49
```

Eu queria tirar a média desses valores repetidos, mas manter a linha. Ficaria assim :

```
Gene              12h        10d         6w

Slc39a10         media     media      media

Mfsd6            media     media      media

Hecw2            media     media      media
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizando o pacote `dplyr`, você pode usar as funções `group_by` (que vai agrupar pelos genes) e `summarise_all` (que irá sumarizar todas as colunas de acordo com uma função pré determinada).

```
library(dplyr)
dados %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)
```

Comment: Valeu, cara. Deu certinho. Obrigado pela ajuda.